# How do I dynamically scrape websites for CSS files based on user input?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

I'm working on a group project where we're trying rank website designs based on the number of colours.
I used a regex to parse through a 'style.css' file that I had already downloaded and got the colour counting down but I'm struggling with the scraping URLs part. I want to be able to access the CSS code straight from whatever URLs the user inputs.

I'm pretty new at programming so I'd appreciate any help offered cause I've been looking at multiple solutions but I don't really understand them or how to reappropriate them for my needs.

Comment: Get the HTML with `requests`, parse it with `bs4`, then look for tags like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[CSS URL]" >`.

Comment: @AlexHall How do you look for tags and what do you do with them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example program that will find all the in-page style data for a page, as well as find all linked style pages and print out everything.  This should get you started, but you'll have to link it up to your color counting system.

```
import urllib.request as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('enter a full website address: ')

html = req.urlopen(url) # request the initial page
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for styles in soup.select('style'): # get in-page style tags
    print('in page style:')
    print(styles.string)

for link in soup.find_all('link', type='text/css'): # get links to external style sheets
    address = link['href'] # the address of the stylesheet
    if address.startswith('/'): # relative link
        address = url + address
    css = req.urlopen(address).read() # make a request to download the stylesheet from the address
    print('linked stylesheet')
    print(css)
```